# UITextField inside UITextView dimiss Keyboard all at once

Tags: ios, resignfirstresponder

I have this setup:  A main `UIView` contains an `UITextView` that has a `UITextField` as subview.  When I dismiss the the keyboard from the `UITextField` using `resignFirstResponder`.  The keyboard is dismissed.  But it animates back again for the `UITextView`.

My desired outcome was to dismiss keyboard completely.

I have tried these individually and combination of one or more:

```
[self endEditing:YES];  // for the main UIView

[myTextView resignFirstResponder];  //UITextView

[myTextField resignFirstResponder];   //UITextField
```

Edit: As it turned out, it just something that I overlooked.
But none seemed to dismiss the keyboard completely.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the "firstResponder" to another view? That's how I dismissed the keyboard in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass UITextView and override some of the UIResponder methods. Namely canBecomeFirstResponder and return NO when the UITextField was the first responder.